# how to use a surfaceview to preview and a surfaceview to record using the same camera in an android app?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder

Now, I have to create an android app that can record a movie and preview. I want to use one surface view for previewing and another invisible for recording using the same camera.

Update:
 I want to click a button and then a tiny surface view which is previewing in the activity disappear, a big one show in a fragment and the big one start to preview. During this process, the recorder has been running.

Comment: another one for what purpose ?

Comment: another one for recording a video. because i want to click a button and then a tiny surface view in the activity disappear and a big one show in a fragment. during this process, the recorder has been running.

Answer (score 0):

From how you explain your use case, it may be easier to connect one surface, and simply resize it (with other layout changes) after button is pressed (and recording starts).

Comment: OK，thank you.But how can I move a surface view from activity to a fragment and then move it to activity?

Comment: No way to "move a view from activity to fragment". What you can do, though, is to prepare a "rectangular hole" in your fragment, so that the preview which is in the activity "under" the fragment is fully displayed.